# Instagram API Request Limitation

Tags: api, request, limit, instagram

According to the API specifications, we are limited to 5.000 requests per hour. We are developing an app for a customer that has 100.000 followers at Instagram, so we will for sure exceed that limit. Is there a way to increase this limitation?

Comment: Probably need to solicit such high-bandwidth applications with Instagram itself. They may give a token with relaxed limits.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase (reset) the requests to 5.000 again by authenticating the user again.

Check here: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

> You are limited to 5000 requests per hour per access_token or
>   client_id overall. Practically, this means you should (when possible)
>   authenticate users so that limits are well outside the reach of a
>   given user.

Comment: Our customers want to browse all the photos from his followers to select a winner photo every day. We are using client_id to access the endpoints. Anyway to receive an acces_token, users are redirected to a login site so it could not be an automatic process.

Comment: did you try to request an access_token with a logged account under the 5.000 limit? i'm not sure, but i think they redirect you to the login page and automatically redirect back with a valid access_token again.